# Background thread returning result of UIImage as nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

This only happens when the Entry has been created on this run of the app. If the Entry is previously created, it fetches the image fine.

This code works fine without using background threads, so it leads me to believe it to be part of the problem. Here's the code I have:

```
NSMutableDictionary *thumbnails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            dispatch_queue_t thumbnailSetupQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.App.SetupTimelineThumbnails", NULL);
            dispatch_async(cellSetupQueue, ^{

                NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread].persistentStoreCoordinator;
                [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

                NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                [notify addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:newMoc];

                Media *media = [localEntry.media anyObject];

                UIImage *image = [media getThumbnail];

                NSLog(@"image: %@", image);

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            });

            dispatch_release(cellSetupQueue);
```

Then

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbnail {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@.jpg",
                           self.mediaID,
                           THUMBNAIL_FILENAME]];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

    NSLog(@"correct size thumbnail: %@", correctSizeThumbnail);

    return correctSizeThumbnail;

}
```

The NSLog in getThumbnailWithSave returns as a UIImage, the other NSLog returns as nil.

Comment: `get` should not be used as a prefix for a method of this type....

Comment: Your question has far too much code in it. If you pare your question down to the areas that are important, it will be much easier for us to figure out what's wrong. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because the image hasn't been created or has already been deallocated when the background thread tries to access it.

Comment: @Dustin I've cut it down a bit now. How can i stop the image from being deallocated, if that may be the problem? What do you mean by it hasn't been created? I showed you all elements of it being created above.

Comment: You're using an `async` operation, so you have to make sure that whenever the background thread needs something it has already been created or isn't removed. It's honestly still too much code for me to go through, but try increasing the scope of the variables required by your background threads.

Comment: It's much shorter now. What do you mean by increasing the scope?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem explained to be a long time ago and I ***think*** this is how I fixed it.

Calling getThumbnail needs to be called back on the main thread.

So adding something such as:

```
UIImage *image;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    image = [media getThumbnail];
});
```

or

```
UIImage *image = [media performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getThumbnail) withObject: nil, waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Again this is off the top of my head but I'm pretty sure this is how I went about it.

Comment: I think you're right. The problem is that this freezes up the UI. Is there an alernative to this? A way to get around it freezing up the UI?

Comment: Maybe move contents of getThumbnail to inside original async block??

Comment: I tried that. It's accessing any item of core data which causes the crash. I think it's something to do with the core data being newly created, because it only happens if the entry's been created in that run.

Comment: Oh I see. My Core Data skills are a bit lacking. I wish I could help more!